# Writing api call log to a file

Tags: playframework, sbt

This is what I tried

ApiLogWriter.java

```
package utils;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class ApiLogWriter {
    FileWriter fw;
    BufferedWriter bw;
    PrintWriter out;

    public ApiLogWriter() {

        try {
            fw = new FileWriter("apiCallLog.txt", true);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            out = new PrintWriter(bw);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void writeToFile(String apiString) {
        out.println(apiString);
        out.flush();
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        if (out != null)
            out.close();
        if (bw != null)
            bw.close();
        if (fw != null)
            fw.close();
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```

ExampleFilter.java

```
package filters;

import akka.stream.Materializer;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.function.Function;
import javax.inject.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.mvc.Http.RequestHeader;
import utils.ApiLogWriter;


/**
 * This is a simple filter that adds a header to all requests. It's
 * added to the application's list of filters by the
 * {@link ExampleFilters} class.
 */
@Singleton
public class ExampleFilter extends Filter {

    private final Executor exec;

    /**
     * @param mat This object is needed to handle streaming of requests
     * and responses.
     * @param exec This class is needed to execute code asynchronously.
     * It is used below by the <code>thenAsyncApply</code> method.
     */
    @Inject
    public ExampleFilter(Materializer mat, Executor exec) {
        super(mat);
        this.exec = exec;
    }

    @Inject
    private ApiLogWriter apiLogWriter;

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> apply(
        Function<RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> next,
        RequestHeader requestHeader) {
        apiLogWriter.writeToFile(requestHeader.path());
        return next.apply(requestHeader).thenApplyAsync(
            result -> result.withHeader("X-ExampleFilter", "foo"),
            exec
        );
    }

}
```

this code works fine when I Run it with sbt Run but file is empty when started up after `sbt stage` from Project_Root/target/universal/stage/bin directory

note that I ran it in dev mode with for `fork in run := false` but in stage build it's true

Comment: Are you sure you look at the right file? You create the file in the current working directory of you server... So, it is probably in the `Project_Root/target/universal/stage/` folder.

Comment: yeah file is being created but it's empty

Comment: actually in the Project_Root/target/universal/stage/bin directory

Comment: Well, it works for me... Do you get the `X-ExampleFilter` header in return when issuing requests?

Comment: no i'm not getting, how to enable this in production run ? @cbley

Comment: Did you enable the filter in the config? E.g. `play.filters.enabled += filters.ExampleFilter`.

Comment: there is not such config currently in the application.cnf

Comment: above syntax seems belongs to build.sbt

Comment: No, this is HOCON syntax which is used in `application.conf`. See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Filters

Comment: So, in general, you have to enable your filter in somehow. Play also prints which filters are enabled when it starts.